# Data Model help for an administrator class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I am trying to build a data model that I can use with Entity Framework 4.1.

I am tring to build a simple app to manage events (like a birthday party). So I figure I will have two types of users, Admins and Attenders. The admins will be able to create and manage the event and the attenders will only be able to view an event they are invited to.

I thought I only needed 2 classes for this but I am not sure. Here is waht I did for EF4.1

```
 public class user
     {
         public int id { get; set; }
         public string name { get; set; }
         public ICollection<myevent> myadminevents { get; set; }
         public ICollection<myevent> myinvites { get; set; }
     }

     public class myevent    {
         public int id { get; set; }
         public string name { get; set; }
         public ICollection<user> admin  { get; set; }
         public ICollection<user> attend { get; set; }
     }


     public class myeventcontext : DbContext
     {
         public DbSet<user> users { get; set; }
         public DbSet<myevent> events { get; set; }
     }
```

EF didnt do what I thought it would. It is ignoring my collections. So I don't think the model is right.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can model this using two junction tables and configure the many-to-many relationships using fluent API

```
public class myeventcontext : DbContext
{

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Entity<User>()
        .HasMany(user => user.myinvites).WithMany(event => event.attend)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("EventAttendees");
                m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                m.MapRightKey("EventId");
            });

        Entity<User>()
        .HasMany(user => user.myadminevents).WithMany(event => event.admin)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("EventAdmins");
                m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                m.MapRightKey("EventId");
            });
     }
}
```

Other approach would be to have a single junction table with an additional column to store whether attendee is is an admin or not. But in this way you will not be able model many-to-many relationship without including the junction table as a class.